# How do I configure WCF to use a custom Realm in URN format with Azure ACS?

Tags: wcf, azure, wif, federated-identity, acs

How do I make my WCF client authenticate using the ACS to my internally hosted WCF service?  The issue revolves around setting a custom Realm (which I can't figure out how to set.)

My ACS is configured similar to [the ACS Samples](http://acs.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=WCF%20Certificate%20Authentication&referringTitle=Samples) however the "Realm" is defined as shown below.

*Excerpt from Azure ACS Configuration page*

---

[image: realm definition]

---

**Client Side Code**

```
      EndpointAddress serviceEndpointAddress = new EndpointAddress( new Uri( "http://localhost:7000/Service/Default.aspx"),  
                                                                      EndpointIdentity.CreateDnsIdentity( GetServiceCertificateSubjectName() ),
                                                                      new AddressHeaderCollection() );

        ChannelFactory<IStringService> stringServiceFactory = new ChannelFactory<IStringService>(Bindings.CreateServiceBinding("https://agent7.accesscontrol.appfabriclabs.com/v2/wstrust/13/certificate"), serviceEndpointAddress );

        // Set the service credentials.
        stringServiceFactory.Credentials.ServiceCertificate.Authentication.CertificateValidationMode = X509CertificateValidationMode.None;
        stringServiceFactory.Credentials.ServiceCertificate.DefaultCertificate = GetServiceCertificate();

        // Set the client credentials.
        stringServiceFactory.Credentials.ClientCertificate.Certificate = GetClientCertificateWithPrivateKey();
```

**Server Side Code**

```
 string acsCertificateEndpoint = String.Format( "https://{0}.{1}/v2/wstrust/13/certificate", AccessControlNamespace, AccessControlHostName );

        ServiceHost rpHost = new ServiceHost( typeof( StringService ) );

        rpHost.Credentials.ServiceCertificate.Certificate = GetServiceCertificateWithPrivateKey();

        rpHost.AddServiceEndpoint( typeof( IStringService ),
                                   Bindings.CreateServiceBinding( acsCertificateEndpoint ),
                                   "http://localhost:7000/Service/Default.aspx"
                                   );

        //
        // This must be called after all WCF settings are set on the service host so the
        // Windows Identity Foundation token handlers can pick up the relevant settings.
        //
        ServiceConfiguration serviceConfiguration = new ServiceConfiguration();
        serviceConfiguration.CertificateValidationMode = X509CertificateValidationMode.None;

        // Accept ACS signing certificate as Issuer.
        serviceConfiguration.IssuerNameRegistry = new X509IssuerNameRegistry( GetAcsSigningCertificate().SubjectName.Name );

        // Add the SAML 2.0 token handler.
        serviceConfiguration.SecurityTokenHandlers.AddOrReplace( new Saml2SecurityTokenHandler() );

        // Add the address of this service to the allowed audiences.
        serviceConfiguration.SecurityTokenHandlers.Configuration.AudienceRestriction.AllowedAudienceUris.Add( new Uri( "urn:federation:customer:222:agent:11") );

        FederatedServiceCredentials.ConfigureServiceHost( rpHost, serviceConfiguration );

        return rpHost;
```

... where `urn:federation:customer:222:agent:11` is the Relying party ID

... and `http://localhost:7000/Service/Default.aspx` is the location I want the above WCF / WIF client to bind to once the ACS authentication is made.

**Question**

How do I edit the code above so that the client and server will both operate against a certain port (localhost:700) and also with a realm of urn:federation:customer:222:agent:11

I think I have the server code correct; however how do I set `AudienceRestriction` on the client?

Comment: and the question is....?

Comment: @Eugenio - updated and clarified

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your server side code looks fine, but Sixto is right about standard channel factories. Luckily, you can request a security token from ACS yourself using a WSTrustChannelFactory. In the context of your sample, your code would look like this:

```
//
// Get the token from ACS
//
WSTrustChannelFactory trustChannelFactory = new WSTrustChannelFactory(
    Bindings.CreateAcsCertificateBinding(),
    new EndpointAddress( acsCertificateEndpoint ) );
trustChannelFactory.Credentials.ClientCertificate.Certificate = GetClientCertificateWithPrivateKey();

RequestSecurityToken rst = new RequestSecurityToken()
{
    RequestType = RequestTypes.Issue,
    AppliesTo = new EndpointAddress( new Uri( "urn:federation:customer:222:agent:11" ) ),
    KeyType = KeyTypes.Symmetric
};

WSTrustChannel wsTrustChannel = (WSTrustChannel)trustChannelFactory.CreateChannel();
SecurityToken token = wsTrustChannel.Issue( rst );

//
// Call StringService, authenticating with the retrieved token
//
WS2007FederationHttpBinding binding = new WS2007FederationHttpBinding( WSFederationHttpSecurityMode.Message );
binding.Security.Message.EstablishSecurityContext = false;
binding.Security.Message.NegotiateServiceCredential = false;

ChannelFactory<IStringService> factory = new ChannelFactory<IStringService>(
    binding,
    new EndpointAddress(
            new Uri( ServiceAddress ),
            EndpointIdentity.CreateDnsIdentity(GetServiceCertificateSubjectName()) ) );
factory.ConfigureChannelFactory<IStringService>();
factory.Credentials.SupportInteractive = false;
factory.Credentials.ServiceCertificate.DefaultCertificate = GetServiceCertificate();

IStringService channel = factory.CreateChannelWithIssuedToken<IStringService>( token );
string reversedString = channel.Reverse( "string to reverse" );
```

Comment: Thanks for the code! This was well worth the +145 rep points.

Comment: What would need to be done if I wanted to have another trust in the the chain?  ADFS to ACS to RP for example?  or ACS to ACS to RP?

Comment: In this scenario, you can still use a WSTrustChannel to get the token, except you would use an IssuedTokenWSTrustBinding, and you'd point it to ACS's issued token endpoint (which is v2/wstrust/13/issuedtoken-symmetric, v2/wstrust/13/issuedtoken-asymmetric, or v2/wstrust/13/issuedtoken-bearer, depending).

You then configure the binding's IssuerBinding and IssuerAddress properties to point to your ADFS certificate endpoint. A search for IssuedTokenWSTrustBinding will yield plenty of code samples.

Once you have the token from ACS, the rest looks the same.

Answer (score 1):

Some answers may be better late than never. I've been unable to find any official documentation on using WCF in this fashion, however in reading the WS-Trust papers and the MSDN documentation on configuration, I have come up with the following solution which appears to work.

From the service consuming client's config at `configuration/system.serviceModel/bindings/ws2007FederationHttpbinding/binding/security/message`. It overrides the `AppliesTo` element of the token request message.

```
<tokenRequestParameters>
  <wsp:AppliesTo xmlns:wsp="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/09/policy">
    <EndpointReference xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing">
      <Address>urn:x-Organization:Testing</Address>
    </EndpointReference>
  </wsp:AppliesTo>
</tokenRequestParameters>
```

Adding this same snippet in the configuration of the service, will cause the Service Reference utility to include this within the `trust:SecondaryParameters` element of the service client. It must be moved into the parent `tokenRequestParameters` element to work properly.

Answer (score 0):

Haven't actually tried [the approach referenced in this MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee517268.aspx) but from reading it sounds like the standard channel factory doesn't have the right hooks to do what you want. The WSTrustChannelFactory is built for WIF & SAML but I'm not familiar enough with ACS to determine if it is applicable. This [article in this six-part series](http://www.leastprivilege.com/WIFADFS2AndWCFndashPart6ChainingMultipleTokenServices.aspx) will probably be worthwhile perusing too.