# SAML WCF webservice

Tags: c#, wcf, wif, saml

I have started working on a WIF saml WCF service. I seem to have everything setup how I think it should, security service, client token WCF service etc. When I run the website that is calling the WCF service it pops-up with a windows card space dialog and the following error in the Windows Event Log.

> Incoming policy failed validation.  No valid claim elements were found in the policy XML.
>
> Additional Information:
>   at System.Environment.get_StackTrace()
>   at Microsoft.InfoCards.Diagnostics.InfoCardTrace.BuildMessage(InfoCardBaseException ie)
>   at Microsoft.InfoCards.Diagnostics.InfoCardTrace.TraceAndLogException(Exception e)
>   at Microsoft.InfoCards.Diagnostics.InfoCardTrace.ThrowHelperError(Exception e)
>   at Microsoft.InfoCards.InfoCardPolicy.Validate()
>   at Microsoft.InfoCards.Request.PreProcessRequest()
>   at Microsoft.InfoCards.ClientUIRequest.PreProcessRequest()
>   at Microsoft.InfoCards.Request.DoProcessRequest(String& extendedMessage)
>   at Microsoft.InfoCards.RequestFactory.ProcessNewRequest(Int32 parentRequestHandle, IntPtr rpcHandle, IntPtr inArgs, IntPtr& outArgs)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From memory, disable Cardspace by setting:

```
ChannelFactory.Credentials.SupportInteractive = false
```

Comment: Do you set this on the website referencing the wcf service?

Comment: Good example here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5598388/how-do-i-configure-wcf-to-use-a-custom-realm-in-urn-format-with-azure-acs

Comment: Where do I set this code snippet?